# SFTP with multiple users

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, chroot, sftp

I want to limit the users to their file. I added the following lines to the sshd configuration file.

```
Match user user1 user2 user3         
        ChrootDirectory /home/%u/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTCPForwarding no
```

When I do "service ssh restart" the following error is displayed :

"Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
".

If I put a single user it works, but how do I add multiple users ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -t` command to check for syntax errors in your configuration file.

In the present case, I believe your Match line should be:

```
Match User user1,user2,user3
```

Note the use of commas.